# Why am i getting Error:- The specified module could not be found even though its present in node_module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to use parcel to create react app
I am new so i will just tell the steps i did

1.npm install -D parcel
I can see parcel in node modules and also parcel in Dev-dependencies
2.npm install react
3.npm install react-dom
3.npx parcel index.html

it gives me this error

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\?\C:\React\node_modules@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\artifacts\index.win32-x64-msvc.node
at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object. (C:\React\node_modules@parcel\source-    map\parcel_sourcemap_node\index.js:15:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Parcel is present so why its still throwing the error that no module found.

Comment: I found the reason its because The issue is because the package is failing due to a missing library on the computer.It requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64).

You can get the download here -> https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe         got this answer from https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7104